# Any idea of how to interleave two lists in dr racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

The problem is when lists have a different length, any idea of how to do it?

I have to use functions like map or something like that

This is the code I wrote so far, it works with lists of the same length but it also needs to work with lists of different lengths. Thank you.

```
(define (interleave list1 list2)
 (flatten [map (lambda (x y) (cons x (cons y null))) list1 list2]))
```

if lists have different length this is what I get:

map: all lists must have same size; arguments were: # '(1 2 3 4 5) '(a b c)

I'm trying to get (1 a 2 b 3 c 4 5)

Comment: Please clarify your question: State what you are doing, show your code and where you're stuck, and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to interleave lists of different lengths. Map function only takes lists of the same length so the problem is when they have different lengths. This is what I'm trying to achieve: for example if you have two lists like (1 2 3 4 5 6) (a b c) the result should be (1 a 2 b 3 c 4 5 6). Or if you have (1 2 3) (a b c d e f) then (1 a 2 b 3 c d e f)

Comment: So edit your question ;) And use formatting tools to highlight your code. See guidelines here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

```
#lang racket

(define (weave xs ys)
  (match (list xs ys)
    [(list (cons x xs) (cons y ys)) (cons x (cons y (weave xs ys)))]
    [(list '() ys)                  ys]
    [(list xs '())                  xs]))
```

Comment: Since there is no comments in the code either, could you please accompany it with some text :) ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your desired behavior is that the lists are interleaved for as long as this is possible, and then whatever is left over from the nonempty list is appended to the end. In that case one possible implementation is

```scm
(define (interleave a b)
  (if (null? a)
      b
      (cons (car a)
            (interleave b (cdr a)))))
```

I think this is probably the simplest possible way to write what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `map` nor `fold-right` would work because they either signal an error when one list is smaller than the other or they tend to stop at the shortest list. eg. [SRFI-1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-1.html)'s [map](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap) `(interleave '(1 2 3 4) (circular-list 9 8)) ; ==> (1 9 2 8 3 9 4 8)`. For a different behavior you need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using simple list manipulation functions might be:

```
 (define (interleave list1 list2)
   (cond ((empty? list1) list2)
         ((empty? list2) list1)
         (else 
          (append 
           (list (car list1) (car list2))
           (interleave (cdr list1) (cdr list2))))))
```

Testing...

```
 > (interleave '(1 2 3 4 5) '(a b c))
 (1 a 2 b 3 c 4 5)
 > (interleave '(1 2 3 4 5) '())
 (1 2 3 4 5)
 > (interleave '() '(a b c))
 (a b c)
 >
```

I think it is fairly self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

*"There ain't *nothin'* you can't not do with `fold-right` and some of them con-tin-uations thingies"*, said a cowboy to another, spittin' into the campfire and puffin' on his cigar in the evening, sippin' his black  coffee from his rugged banged up tin mug. *"*Yessa*, nothin' in the whole darn world."*

```
(define (interleave xs ys)

    ;; interleave xs ys = foldr g n xs ys
    ;;    where
    ;;    g x r (y:ys) = x : y : r ys
    ;;    g x r []     = x : r []
    ;;    n ys         = ys

    ((foldr
       (lambda (x r)
         (lambda (ys) 
           (cond ((null? ys) (cons x (r '())))
                 (else (apply (lambda (y . ys)
                                 (cons x (cons y (r ys))))
                              ys)))))
       (lambda (ys) ys)
       xs)
     ys))
```