# Assigning random values to the elements of a list

Tags: list, random, racket

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071930/any-idea-of-how-to-interleave-two-lists-in-dr-racket) we can construct an interleaved list out of two lists with a different length (according to Sylwester answer making use of *circular-list*). My question is how can we do the same but taking the elements of the second list randomly.

That is, I want to assign to the elements of a list a random value out of a list. For example: given the *assigning list* '(0 1) and whatever list '(a b c d) I want as the output a list such as '((a 0) (b 0) (c 1) (d 0)) or '((a 1) (b 0) (c 0) (d 1)) for example.

My attempts are:

1. > (map cons '(a b c d) (circular-list (random '(0 1))))

which gives '((a . 0) (b . 0) (c . 0) (d . 0)) or '((a . 1) (b . 1) (c . 1) (d . 1)) and nothing different and

2. > (map cons '(a b c d) (list (random '(0 1))))

which gives '((a . 0)) or '((a . 1)) and nothing different.

PS: I am making use of a function called *random* and defined as

> (define (random lst) (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))

which in my example would take randomly 0 or 1 out of a list '(0 1).

Comment: What is the result of `(random '(0) '(1))` ? (Which language are you using? (Racket, one of the teaching languages, other)

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusion, you should rename your new "`random`" function on lists to `random-element` or something similar. That way both people reading your code, and Racket, will know the difference.

```
random : PositiveNaturalNumber -> NaturalNumber

random-element : [NonEmptyListof X] -> X
```

These two different functions need to have two different names so that when you want to refer to the first one `random` from Racket, you can do so. Otherwise Racket (as well as other people reading your code) will think you mean `random-element` when you really want `random`.

This confusion matters in the body of your definition of "`random`":

```
;           /--------------<< This should be renamed to `random-element`
;          \/
(define (random lst)
  (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))
;                  /\
;                   \------<< This is meant to be the original Racket `random`
;                             but it ends up referring to "random-element" because
;                             of the naming conflict
```

Because of this name conflict, when this definition of `random` is put in a *File*, and I run a Repl for that File, I get an error like this:

```
> (random '(A B C D E F G))
length: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: 7
```

When this is renamed, the definition should look like this:

```
;; random-element : [NonEmptyListof X] -> X
(define (random-element lst)
  (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))
;                  /\
;                   \-------<< This is the `random` from Racket, not the "new" one
```

Using it:

```
> (random-element '(A B C D E F G))
'E
> (random-element '(A B C D E F G))
'B
> (random-element '(A B C D E F G))
'D
> (random-element '(A B C D E F G))
'F
> (random-element '(A B C D E F G))
'C
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifcation. It has been formative. However, my function still gives the same value for all (a b c d):  '((a . 0) (b . 0) (c . 0) (d . 0)) or '((a . 1) (b . 1) (c . 1) (d . 1)). @PetSerAl answer works fine but I don't understand why we need to convert the list into a vector yet (let alone the fact that it does not work in DrRacket, only in the Ubuntu terminal).

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert it to a vector. However, I suspect that my answer here combined with an answer to [How to create a list with n applications of a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024035/how-to-create-a-list-with-n-applications-of-a-procedure) will solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The comments can't contain code fragments, so ...

What does this program give?

```
#lang racket
(require srfi/1)
(random '(0) '(1))
```

On my computer with Racket 7.0 I get:

```
random: contract violation
  expected: exact-integer?
  given: '(0)
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

Comment: 'random' is a function I have written. It is actually more complex, I wanted to simplify the question since my interest is on the "interleaving part". For example: (define (random lista) (list-ref lista (random (length lista)))). Sorry for that.

Comment: In my Ubuntu terminal (random '(0 1)) returns 0 or 1.